# Magento exception Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'value' cannot be null' in \lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:234

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.4

I am running an Observer Method using following way manually to test it

```
<?php
require_once('app/Mage.php');
umask(0);
Mage::app();

$observer = Mage::getModel('promoproductcategoryassign/observer');
$observer->updatePromoCategoryProducts();
```

code in Observer is as following :

```
public function updatePromoCategoryProducts()
{        
    $store = '1';
    $assignedCategories = array();
    $promoCatId = (int)Mage::getStoreConfig('promoprodsec/promoprodgroup/promocategoryid');
    $products = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($promoCatId)
        ->getProductCollection();       
    $products->addAttributeToSelect('*');
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);
    $products->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Visibility::VISIBILITY_BOTH);

    foreach ($products as $prod) {        
        $prodId = (int)$prod->getId();
        $validDateFlag = Mage::app()->getLocale()->isStoreDateInInterval(
            $store,
            $prod->getData('special_from_date'),
            $prod->getData('special_to_date')
        );

        $assignedCategories = $prod->getCategoryIds();
        array_pop($assignedCategories);

        if ($validDateFlag == false || $specialPrice == '') {

            $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($prodId);
            $product->setCategoryIds($assignedCategories);
            $product->save();
        }
    }
}
```

It throws following exception :

```
Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'value' cannot be null' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1452): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Abstract.php(228): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
#6 C:\xam in C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php on line 234
```

I tried to debug it by enabling the mysql query logging from `\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php` file.

I get following in the `/var/debug/sql.txt file`

```
    ## 2516 ## QUERY
SQL: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_int` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=VALUES(`value`)
BIND: Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 114
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 6281
    [4] => 
)

AFF: 1
TIME: 0.0005

## 2516 ## QUERY
SQL: INSERT INTO `catalog_product_entity_varchar` (`entity_type_id`, `attribute_id`, `store_id`, `entity_id`, `value`) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `value`=VALUES(`value`)
BIND: Array
(
    [0] => 4
    [1] => 116
    [2] => 0
    [3] => 6281
    [4] => 
)

TIME: 0.0016

EXCEPTION 
exception 'Zend_Db_Statement_Exception' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'value' cannot be null' in C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement\Pdo.php:234
Stack trace:
#0 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Statement.php(300): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Abstract.php(468): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#2 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Zend\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#3 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(333): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#4 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\lib\Varien\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql.php(1452): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query('INSERT INTO `ca...', Array)
#5 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Resource\Eav\Mysql4\Abstract.php(228): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->insertOnDuplicate('catalog_product...', Array, Array)
#6 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(1158): Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Abstract->_insertAttribute(Object(OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product), Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Eav_Attribute), NULL)
#7 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Eav\Model\Entity\Abstract.php(955): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->_processSaveData(Array)
#8 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Abstract.php(306): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract->save(Object(OrganicInternet_SimpleConfigurableProducts_Catalog_Model_Product))
#9 C:\xampp\htdocs\mymagento\muk_specialpriceupdates.php(12): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->save()
#10 {main}

## 2516 ## TRANSACTION ROLLBACK
TIME: 0.0511
```

How can I fix this? (Magento version 1.4.1.1)

Answer (score 1):

`array_pop($assignedCategories);` is removing the last item of the categories array, if the array only has one element(if the product is only assigned to one category) then what left is an empty array, thus making the `value` of the `category_ids` attribute an empty string `''` which triggers the `NOTNULL` constraint violation error on the EAV table.
the solution would be to remove `array_pop($assignedCategories);`

Comment: Even if I pass hard code value instead of $assignedCategories then also I am getting error

Comment: $product->setCategoryIds('10');
            $product->save();

Comment: what are the product EAV attribute_ids 114 and 116 in your install?

Comment: Under eav_attribute table :  114   links_purchased_separately and  116  links_title

Comment: Then it looks like those values are either required or you are setting empty data, it could be a new attribute that has not yet be assigned to the products that you iterating through

Comment: you are right but I am able to find out where these values are being used

Comment: Is there a programmatic way to find out this?

Comment: try a `var_dump` on `$product->debug()`